# circuitikz connection missplacement

Tags: circuitikz

i have the following code:

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC}

....


\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0,0) node[nand port] (nand1) {}
        (nand1.in 2) -- (nand1.out)
        (nand1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$x(t)$}
        (nand1.out) node[anchor=west] {$y(t)$};
\end{circuitikz}
```

The code should create a nand gate with a loop like this:

[image: connection ok]

But somehow the loop connection is routed through the gate:

[image: connection not ok]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too complicated for a comment, but I would suggest the following  modifications to AboAmmar's answer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american ports]
    \draw
        (0,0) node[nand port] (nand1) {}
        (nand1.in 2) -- ++(0,-5mm)-| (nand1.out)
        to[short,*-] ++(5mm,0) node[anchor=west] {$y(t)$}
        (nand1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$x(t)$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: corrected]

Comment: This solution seems to be the cleanest thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0,0) node[nand port] (nand1) {}
        (nand1.in 2) --++(0,-5mm)-| (nand1.out)
        --++(5mm,0) node[anchor=west] {$y(t)$}
        (nand1.in 1) node[anchor=east] {$x(t)$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So far as I know, `circuitikz` doesn't have libraries `circuits.logic.US` and `circuits.logic.IEC`, even more, mixing `circuitikz` and `TikZ` can make problems. Anyway, since my answer is almost the same in you were faster in uploading, I erase mine :-)

Comment: I have a couple of suggestions, as shown below (above?).